Is Selfie Dog the reason my RPC provider sent me a ‘calm down’ email?
I’m building an integration for Selfie Dog (you know, the dog takes selfies).
It started innocently enough: upload selfies → mint streak NFTs → reward $SELFIE tokens.
Simple, right?
Here’s where it got weird:

My Helius RPC dashboard started spiking so hard I thought someone launched a botnet.
Holly (Helius support legend) DMed me asking if I was “okay.”
My validator logs look like I’m trying to simulate the entire Ethereum merge on Solana. I swear I heard Vitalik whisper in the wind: “That’s a lot of selfies.”

For context:

I’m batching mints for Proof-of-Wag NFTs because Selfie Dog users really like snapping selfies.
Users are uploading streaks like “Day 67 of my hat challenge.”
I’m now hitting rate limits faster than a memecoin launch, and Helius flagged my account like I’m about to crash Solana (again).

My Questions:

How do I batch these selfie mints efficiently without causing RPC throttling?
Is there an RPC provider that specifically supports “dog-induced on-chain spam”?
Should I stop blaming Selfie Dog and just optimize my compute budget?

Here’s the meme causing all my troubles.   
9WPTUkh8fKuCnepRWoPYLH3aK9gSjPHFDenBq2X1Czdp

